# Check UITextfield interval of numbers

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How can I check if the value from an UITextField is an interval of numbers between 1 - 100 and IF the number IS in that interval to send the value to another UIViewController? If the value in not in that interval then to show an alert.

My other controller have a `var receivedValue = ""`  which I will use it to populate a UILabel.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var insertNumberTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        insertNumberTextField.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func checkNumberIntervalButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if insertNumberTextField.text == "\(1..<100)"{
            print("Number is in interval 1 - 100.")

            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try again", message: "Sorry but this numer is not in the inverval 1 - 100. Try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            insertNumberTextField.text = ""

            print("Number is not in the inverval 1 - 100.")
        }
    }
}

extension ChildViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the text field's text into an `Int` and compare it that way.

```
if let text = insertNumberTextField.text, let value = Int(text), (0 ..< 100).contains(value) {
    // number is between 1 and 100
} else {
    // show alert
}
```

Comment: `UITextField.text` is an optional property, it has to be unwrapped.

Comment: it will always return ""